# textFieldDidBeginEditing func is not being called when tapping on a text field

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a project with three views that are all multiple textFields that call a UIPickerView when tapped. I have two of the views working just fine but when I started on the third one I cannot get the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` function to be called. I confirmed this by putting a break point at the first line of the function. When I run, the breakpoint is never hit, even when I tap on any of the fields in the view. I copied and pasted the code from the other views, changing the variable names.

Each of the textFields are initialized in the `viewDidLoad` method to the dataPickerView variable I defined in the prior code. The `dataPickerView.delegate = self` and `dataPickerView.dataSource = self` also.

Here is what I think is the relevant code. I'm sure there is something simple I am missing

```
@IBOutlet var enterDispPhys: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var enterUser: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var enterInsurance: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var enterBodyPart: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.userLabel.text = userName
    self.teamLabel.text = teamName

    //initialize the inputView of the dispensing physician field to the PickerView
    enterDispPhys.inputView = dataPickerView

    //initialize the inputView of the user name field to the PickerView
    enterUser.inputView = dataPickerView

    //initialize the inputView of the insurance field to the PickerView
    enterInsurance.inputView = dataPickerView

    //initialize the inputView of the body part field to the PickerView
    enterBodyPart.inputView = dataPickerView

    dataPickerView.delegate = self
    dataPickerView.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    activeDataArray == [] //clear out the clicked field data array
    if textField == enterDispPhys {
        activeDataArray = dispPhys
    } else
        if textField == enterUser {
            activeDataArray = userNameList
    } else
        if textField == enterInsurance {
            activeDataArray = insCode
    } else
        if textField == enterBodyPart {
            activeDataArray = bodyPart
    }
    dataPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    dataPickerView.hidden = false
    println(activeDataArray)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you set you class declaration to implement the text field delegate? Also did you set the delegate for each field? I like to do using observers as the email field bellor, but you can also add it in viewDidLoad as in the password field too.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!{
        didSet{email.delegate = self}
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        password.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have the UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource implemented in the class declaration.

Comment: Did you setup all the delegates for each text field? I add the answer above

Comment: The answer to your question is no, I do not have each textField.delegate = self.  However, in the other two views where I use this technique, I have the textFields set up the same way. From the code each of the textFields.inputView = dataPickerView.  Why in this view would I need to add code for each textField's delegate but not in the other views? I have edited the original post to show the IBOutlet code.

Comment: I think a better question is how the other view is working as for a textfield to respond to its delegate you must set its delegate to the class you want it to respond to.

Comment: I chose your first solution as part of the IBOutlet. I still don't know why this was needed in this view but not the others.  I have compared the code side by side and I don't see a step I missed.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: That's great! I like the first better as well, It could be that something else is causing it to happen in the other view controller, I would play safe and implement the same in there just to be sure it will work in all phones and future versions etc. Good luck with your app!